# Access to disposed closure

Tags: c#, async-await, task-parallel-library

```
using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
{
    await
        response
            .Content
            .CopyToAsync(memoryStream)
            .ContinueWith(
                copyTask =>
                {
                    using (var import = new Import())
                    {
                        var data = memoryStream.ToArray();
                        import.SaveDocumentByRecordNum(data, fileName, items[0]);
                        memoryStream.Close();
                    }
                });
}
```

1. I get an exception warning Access to disposed object on the inner using block.
2. Is memoryStream.close() statement necessary or is it redundant?

Please suggest how to improve this piece of code.

Comment: You should provide code that can be tested. Right now I cannot run your code to see what the issue is. It would be ideal if you could write a simple, compilable piece of code that demonstrates the issue with the exception. That way you are more likely to get a good answer.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

the warning you get is because the compiler is not smart enough to know you will never be outside of the memory stream's `using` block when you use the `MemoryStream` in the `ContinueWith`.

You normally do not mix async/await and `ContinueWith`, switching over to just using async/await by itself will also fix your warning. The following code will be have just like your old one but not cause the warning.

```
using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
{
    await response.Content.CopyToAsync(memoryStream).ConfigureAwait(false);

    using (var import = new Import())
    {
        var data = memoryStream.ToArray();
        trimImport.SaveDocumentByRecordNum(data, fileName, items[0]);
    }    
}
```

Also calling `Close()` on any `Stream` based object is redundant<sup>1</sup> when it is in a `using` statement as disposing of it will close the stream also.

---

<sup>1: It is also redundant because MemoryStream.Close() is not overridden and the [base class just calls Dispose(true)](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/mscorlib/system/io/stream.cs.html#dc4ffe046b847b84) and [MemoryStream.Dispose(bool)](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/io/memorystream.cs,0b83d17ca69bf8ea) does not do anything other than mark the stream as not writeable.</sup>